# Cannot install Guest Additions on Windows 7 guest and openSUSE 11.4 host

Tags: opensuse, virtualbox

I'm using openSUSE as a host and Windows 7 as a guest, the problem is that I cannot find guest tools.iso, pushing on Install Guest Tools does nothing.

Could somebody tell where I can download iso file of guest tools?

Answer (score 1):

The VirtualBox Guest Additions ISO for VirtualBox 4.0.6 (just go to the parent directory for other versions) can be found here:

http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.0.6/